# Combo Jack Mic on Asus Laptop F552C

Tags: audio, asus

I have tried to plug my headset in the combo jack of my laptop to record with Audacity. I had the same problem not only with elementary OS, but also with Ubuntu. I have tried to use alsa-gui-tools , but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: When I plug my headset or my handsfree, the OS can recognize only the audio(output), not the microphone input.

Comment: Are you plugging this into a 3.5 mm green port? It is likely your computer doesn't support this 2 in 1 connector. Does it have 2 plugs, one green one pink to go in - or a USB as well, or is it just a green plug?

Comment: It's a black one (3.5mm). With my headset I use a 2-in-1 connector. When using my handsfree, I plug them in directly. It worked properly with Windows.